# Remove .html from url through .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am using following code in Localhost after some some apache settings it is working fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

But when I upload this .htaccess file on hosting server then showing error 404. When I check online .htaccess tester it is showing `"This variable is not supported: %{REQUEST_FILENAME}"`

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located on hosting server?

Comment: in the root directory besides Index.html file.

Comment: Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: Are you running apache? If you are running another server, such as lighttpd it won't even look at .htaccess.

Comment: when I put some code .htaccess file it will show the error 500 on landing page.

Comment: create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value. Make sure you htaccess at same path.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```